# Prove that the partial order ((D * D), ⊆) is a complete partial order with bottom.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, programming

Let D be a non-empty set and (D-->D) be the set of all partial functions
from D to D. Prove that the partial order ((D--> D), ⊆) (i.e., the set of
partial functions ordered by set inclusion) is a complete partial order with
bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The empty function is the bottom.

It is not complete.
Let D = {0,1}, f = { (0,1), (1,1) }, g = { (0,0), (1,0) }.
There is no upper bound for {f,g}, nor is there a top.

It is however meet complete.
If F not empty subset D*D, then inf F = $\cap$F.

It is also chain complete.
If K subset D*D is a chain, then sup K = $\cup$K.

Comment: actually i have done some mistakes while asking a question. if you answer it again , i shall be gratefull to you.